# determinant of independent set of triangles

Tags: combinatorics, field-theory

let $n > 3$. To a square free trinomial $x_i x_j x_k$ associate the $n$ vector that has all entries zeros except in the $i$-th, $j$-th, and $k$-th entries, where it has the value $1$ (i.e. all zeroes except $1$'s in $3$ places).

Consider a set of $n$ square-free trinomials $t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_n$ such that their associated vectors are independent (say over $\mathbb C$).

True of false: the determinant of the $n$ independent triangles is $2^a \times 3^b$, for some positive integers $a, b$ (i.e. only the primes $2$ and $3$ divide the determinant).